# Removing textures from Forge model

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am trying to remove textures from my Forge model as in my case I don't need them. I tried following [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/showhide-textures-object-forge-viewer) but none of my materials are returning a "map" parameter, even though there are textures shown in the model. Has there been a change to the API since this was written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with the latest Viewer (v6.5) and can confirm that API is still valid:

```
viewer.addEventListener(viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT, ()=>{
            let mats = viewer.impl.matman()._materials;
            Object.keys(mats).forEach(k=>console.log(mats[k].map))
}))
```

See live sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/73a95kLf/).

Did you wait till all textures are loaded to call the API?

Comment: This worked. I was calling it from onModelLoadSuccess. The textures must not be loaded at that point. Thank you